# Can't connect to TeamCity server itself

Tags: java, centos, teamcity

I've seen a lot of posts on the build agent not being able to connect to the server, but in my case I can't connect to the server at all.

I'm using TeamCity 10, on CentOS 7 with the Oracle JDK installed. I've started the server using the runAll script and have not changed anything in the configuration. I opened port 8111 with FirewallD to access the setup screen.

The problem is, I can't access the setup screen. I open the page in Chrome and it just hangs "connecting". I tried Firefox too, and also CURL. It appears that the TCP connection is accepted, and the HTTP request is sent, but no response comes at all.

The logs do not show that anything is wrong. The build agent log fails to register to the server, however, saying it is in "maintenance mode". This is a fresh install.

Comment: Did you open port 8111 for TCP? (UDP only won't help.) Are you sure TeamCity is configured to run on port 8111? Is there any other firewall in between you and the TeamCity server?

Comment: Yes I did open it for TCP. It's not a firewall problem, as running curl on the server to local host also hangs. The docker image also results in the same.